# Global Thread in WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am really newbie in WPF development. I want to develop thread that always check the web api as long as application is opened. I want to start the thread when the application is open and keep running until the whole application exit.

Comment: You cannot learn WPF through trial and error. You need to get a book or follow a tutorial. Unfortunately, SO is not able to do either for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can kick off a long running task in the constructor of your codebehind or your mainviewmodel.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing long running thread");
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                //update textbox on UI
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => textBox.Text = i.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                i++;
            }

        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't suggest something like that. There are many really bad design decisions in your code, but a newbie could take this all as a good solution.